# Laravel how to join multiple hasMany tables but without repeat record?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I got 3 tables which is products, stocks, and costs. I need to write a query to return a total quantity and total value for each products.

products table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

stocks table

| product_id | stock |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | -2 |
| 2 | 1 |

costs table

| product_id | cost_per_unit | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 20 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2 | 30 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 40 | 2022-01-02 |

```
DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));");

$result = Product::query()
->leftJoin('stocks', 'stocks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
->leftJoin('costs', function($join){
   $join->on('costs.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
   ->orderByDesc('date')
   ->limit(1);
})
->select([
   'products.name',
   DB::raw("SUM(stocks.qty) as total_qty"),
   DB::raw("SUM(stocks.qty) * costs.cost_per_unit as total_value"),
])
->groupBy('products.id')
->get();
```

Result output:-

[image]

Expected result:-

```
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "A"
    "total_qty" => "1" (1)
    "total_value" => "20.00" (1 * 20)
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "B"
    "total_qty" => "1" (2 + -2 + 1)
    "total_value" => "40.00" (1 * 40)
  ]
```

after I join multiple hasMany table I think the table will look something like this,

so for product A total_qty become 1+1=2 and total_value become 2*20=40

for product B total_qty become 2+2+-2+-2+1+1=2 and total_value become 2*40=80

*total_value = total_qty * cost_per_unit(latest date)

| product_id | stock | cost_per_unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | 40 |
| 2 | -2 | 30 |
| 2 | -2 | 40 |
| 2 | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 |

So how can i fix this?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [mre] to improve it before submitting it. There is a lot of missing details as for example, using aggregated fields without aggregation, Database structure makes no send as you expose it..etc

Comment: @N69S add this line so it wont get aggregate error DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));"); not sure why my existing project dont have to add this line, but i get aggregate error when i run the query in new project without adding this line

Comment: just side info, you dont need to add that line, go to config/database.php and turn strict mode off `'strict' => false,`. it is NOT RECOMMENDED but that is how you do it, no need to add a raw query each time.

Comment: in your structure, how do you know which "stock" is which "cost_per_unit" for the same product ? Product id = 2 has stock (2 and -2) and cost (20, 30 and 40). how do you know it's 2 => 20 and -2 => 30 and not 2 => 40 and -2 => 20 ?!

Comment: @N69S stocks table will record all the stock in and stock out transaction if you want to get the product stock balance you have to sum all the record, cost_per_unit always use the latest date one, you dont have to know which transaction is which cost

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupBy()` will fix the issue

```
$result = Product::query()
->leftJoin('stocks', 'stocks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
->leftJoin('costs', function($join){
   $join->on('costs.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
   ->orderByDesc('date')
   ->limit(1);
})
->select([
   'products.name',
   DB::raw("SUM(stocks.qty) as total_qty"),
   DB::raw("SUM(stocks.qty) * costs.cost_per_unit as total_value"),
])
->groupBy('products.id')
->get();
```

Comment: sorry i got use groupBy() in my query, i just forget to write it in my question